# Creating a Table in XAML and populating it with an Array?

Tags: arrays, xaml, windows-phone-8, grid, auto-populate

If I have a table like the one below:

```
 <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ShowGridLines="True" Width="250" Height="100">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0">2005 Products Shipped</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Quarter 1</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">Quarter 2</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">Quarter 3</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">50000</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">100000</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">150000</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="3">Total Units: 300000</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

Would I be able to populate it in one go using an array.

For example, if I had an Array containing "Row 1", "Row 2" etc. thru 10 would I be able to populate the first column with those values?

I'm not sure I'm doing a great job of explaining. I know I could do each cell individually, but I want it to cycle through and do all at once?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, consider just using a ListBox or ItemsControl, with a DataTemplate.  Define the 2 header rows in a separate grid, and stack this one underneath.  The catch with this approach is that you need to define fixed-width columns, since each row will be its own Grid (or actually StackPanel is more performant in this scenario):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TheArray}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding Col1}" />
                <TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding Col2}" />
                <TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding Col3}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Secondly, if you need to use a true Grid, then one approach could be to define a Behavior on your Grid.  This Behavior class would define an `Items` dependency property.  The dependency property's "changed" handler could then create the TextBlocks (x of them for each cell where x is the number of columns), add them to the Grid, and assign the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` properties (and even add the `RowDefinitions` if necessary).

```
<Grid>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <my:GridItemsBehavior Items="{Binding TheArray}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Grid>
```

I wouldn't necessarily recommend the latter approach, because you lose a lot of the power of XAML by creating UI in code-behind.

Comment: The overhead of implementing this is far greater than just binding each textbox with a separate data source. @Dan James Palmer Any particular reason you wanna do it this way?

Comment: @Pantelis I'm not sure I follow.  You mean create 3 columns x 10 rows = 30 separate bindings?  I suppose that is an option ... actually, a `StackPanel` would be possible with fixed-width columns, and better performing that `Grid` (updated).

Comment: 4 rows. 12 Properties. Its not that much.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the "through 10" in the OP. I was counting the declared rows definitions.

Comment: 10 was just the example, it would most likely be more in most cases I have in mind. 

I was just thinking of a cleaner way to do it. I can just assign each value individually, if that's best?

Comment: No, if thas the case, what @McGarnagle suggests is the way to go. The first suggestion since it does not require code-behind which should be avoided whenever possible with XAML technologies.